# Blindly parse XML page for specific tags

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, tinyxml

I'm having trouble using [TinyXML2](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/) to *blindly* parse a XML page for specific tags.

Basically, I am asked to parse via C++ an HTML page. I use the (quite old) tidyHTML library to firstly "translate" my HTML pages into XML ones. Then, I want to use TinyXML2 to parse these newly created XML pages for **specific tags' content** (title, h1, meta keywords, ...).

To this end, I am trying to loop through all the tags in my XML page, using this code:

```
XMLDocument doc;
doc.Parse( cleanedHTML.c_str() );
XMLNode* currentNode;

if(currentNode->NoChildren())
{
    while(!currentNode->NextSibling())
    {
        currentNode=currentNode->Parent();
        if(!currentNode)
            return NULL;
    }
    currentNode=currentNode->NextSibling();
}
else
{
    currentNode=currentNode->FirstChild();
}

doc.Print();
std::string nodeName = currentNode->LastChild()->Value();
return nodeName;
```

There are probably a few things wrong with this code - no doubt, I'm clearly an amateur. But the result still puzzles me: nodeName is returning "**USER=root**" whatever the page I am parsing.

I tried selecting this node's related elements, like currentNode->**FirstChildElement()** or **LastChildElement()**, or even Siblings... But everytime it results in a **Segmentation Fault** which I cannot comprehend.

I've read that **Xpath** would be a good way to do what I'm trying to do, but then again I'm running out of time and I fear I wouldn't be able to wrap my mind around Xpath in such relatively short notice.

I probably am looking at all that the wrong way, or maybe should I be using **[Accept()](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2docs/classtinyxml2_1_1_x_m_l_node.html#a81e66df0a44c67a7af17f3b77a152785)** ?
I honestly feel a bit lost here and would appreciate any help you guys would be so kind as to offer!
*I'd like to quickly take this chance to also thank this website that has helped me so much in the past.
Truely amazing.*

Thanks by advance for your responses!

Comment: have you verified the "cleaned" XML is in fact, **valid** XML ?

Comment: Well I'm trying firstly with a very simple code (6 elements and a dozen nodes top) and well... xmlvalidation.com does not encounter any errors. I am now going to try to parse similarly but only **ELEMENTS** and via a **FOR** loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I've finished my project I can finally answer this:

What I was looking for indeed was **Accept()** and **Visitors**. I had to **instantiate** a Visitor, add any particular effect his "encounters" would produce, and throw it into my *doc.Accept();*

For instance, if I wanted to get in a string the parsed page's title, I would do so:

`bool MyVisitor::VisitEnter(const XMLElement& element, const XMLAttribute* attribute)
    if(strcmp( element.Name(), "title") == 0)
    {
        if(element.GetText() != NULL)
        {
            titleContent = element.GetText();
        }
        else
            titleContent = "";
    }`

... and then return it with a *classic* MyVisitor::getTitle() function that you'd call wherever you'd need it.
Hope it helps, if anyone wants more details I can provide working & extended code.

I've since discovered that Google released **[gumbo parser](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser)** so... yeah.
It's *apparently* both better & easier than using TinyXML-2 for parsing HTML5 nowadays :D

Answer (score -2):

You might want to consider using a parser for which better examples are available, upon which you could base your tool... for example, Apache Xerces-C's SAX API examples could be adapted.

(I don't know anything about TinyXML2 and what APIs it supports, so I can't advise re how to fix the problem in your existing code.)

Comment: Thank you for your interest ! I think TinyXML2 already has something close to a SAX Interface ([Accept()](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2docs/classtinyxml2_1_1_x_m_l_node.html#a81e66df0a44c67a7af17f3b77a152785)) but ... Is that really what I want to do ? I'll look a bit more into SAX in any case.